# ChromeDriver unzipping 85.0.4183.38 version instead of 84.0.4147.89 using WebdriverManager for Selenium Protractor

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I am trying to execute **webdirver-manager** update command. But chrome driver unzipping 85.0.4183.38 instead of 84.0.4147.89 as my chrome browser version is 84.0.4147.89.
I tried the following:

1. Webdriver-manager update --version.chrome=84.0.4147.89
   a.  Downgrading the driver for browser compatible version.
2. Uninstalling & reinstalling Chrome
3. Uninstalling & reinstalling chromedriver / protractor / webdriver
4. Webdriver-manager update --version.chrome 2.28
   a.  Downgrading the driver for browser version 54+

Still I am getting the error:

```
E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the usual case when you use [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor#protractor---). However as per the discussions in:

- [Protractor 7.0.0 only supports chrome verison 85, while chrome version is 85 (error)](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5460)
- [webdriver-manager update downloads an incompatible version of chromedriver](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/376)

As of now there seems to be some discrepancy in downloading the latest stable [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871). The [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) repository clearly suggests:

- *Current **stable** release: [ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/)*
- *Current **beta** release: [ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.38](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=85.0.4183.38/)*

So as the current [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser version is *Version 84.0.4147.89*, *ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30* should have been downloaded and installed.

---

### Solution

As per `@Fuun347`'s [comment](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5460#issuecomment-663535677) the solution is to:

- Add version arguments to the webdriver-manager update and start commands. Updating and starting your webdriver with these commands will force the version to always be 84:

  ```
  webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=84.0.4147.30
  webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=84.0.4147.30
  ```

> **Note**: Running ng e2e --project=e2e-no-serve --specs=./src/service/ --webdriverUpdate=false will stop the angular-cli from trying to update the webdriver.

Further, `@TylerNielsen` in his [comment](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/376#issuecomment-663560439) added:

> The following worked for us:
>
> We have webdriver-manager installed as project dependency.
>
> we call webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 84.0.4147.30 prior
> to running our tests. This will install the 84 chromedriver version in
> ./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/. (We just made this as a
> npm script in our package.json)
>
> We then update the protractor.conf file to have this line in the root
> of exports.config:
> chromeDriver:"./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30.exe"**
>
> Protractor still installs chromedriverr 85, but it will use the 84
> version.
>
> In our case, we run our protractor tests in docker, but develop mostly on windows. So I updated the protractor.conf to have this line
> so that it works in either: chromeDriver: process.platform === "win32"
> ?
> "./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30.exe"
> :
> "./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30"

Answer (score 0):

Please re download chrome driver exe according to your browser version (https://chromedriver.chromium.org)Your browser versions are updating time to time so you need to use exact driver exe.